# What prevents Hong Kong from punishing people who committed crimes in China in Hong Kong?

Tags: law, china, hong-kong

What prevents Hong Kong from punishing people who committed crimes in China in Hong Kong? As you know, there were a lot of protests against the extradition law that the government of Hong Kong wanted to pass, but I was wondering if China wanted to really punish them, why wouldn't they allow Hong Kong to punish the people who committed illegal acts in China to be tried in Hong Kong under Hong Kong's laws and sent to a Hong Kong prison? Is there something in the law that prevents Hong Kong to do so? Is there absolutely no way for Hong Kong to do this?

Comment: I don't know anything about Chinese law, but in the West legal systems don't try people for crimes that weren't committed in their jurisdictions.

Comment: @IllusiveBrian Sometimes they do, for example there have been successful prosecutions of sex tourists who have raped children in other countries. There is special provision in UK law for this.

Comment: I have no law information precise enough to write an answer, but I strongly suspect that China wants to be able to prosecute citizens for political offenses (e.g., criticizing the Party) that would not be considered delictuous in democratic-leaning Hong-Kong, and not be prosecuted there.

Comment: @Evargalo There is also no strong incentive for mainland China to respect the decisions of a Hong Kong court, and Hong Kong certainly couldn't force that unilaterally. Also, everyone should note that officially Hong Kong is a part of China, it's just special.

Comment: @IllusiveBrian: As a general rule, that’s true, but there are a number of exceptions. E.g., Germany and Switzerland (reasonably Western) don’t extradite their citizens; but, say, a German who committed murder in the US and managed to return undetected could be tried in Germany.

Comment: @chirlu do you know if it the case in general, or was murder [or other crimes that could result into capital punishment in the US] an exception? I mean, a country like Germany would refuse to hand over a person to any country, if the person risks getting a death penalty there. I was not aware such a person could then face a trial in Germany, but that of course sounds fair, since, otherwise he/she would otherwise just walk free.

Comment: (Ir)Rel. to my comment above, as a curiosity: It is sometimes possible for a non-citizen serving a prison sentence in a country X [sentence handed by a court there typically for a crime committed there], to request to get transferred to serve the prison sentence in his own country. I wonder if e.g. Germany would agree to hand over an American, who has, by a German court, been convicted of a murder in the US, and given a [short in US standards] prison sentence, over to US to serve his/her sentence there. Quite theoretical question, as maybe the person would decide not to apply for the transfer.

Comment: @Tuomo: Germany will never extradite a German citizen to a non-EU country, whatever the possible sentence (constitutional guarantee) – except of course if the suspect agrees. Germany may extradite a foreign citizen, to their country of citizenship or a third country, but indeed not if they risk the death penalty there, or torture or an unfair trial. However, extradition of a foreign citizen to (e.g.) the US is possible if the US promises not to apply the death penalty in that particular case, and that does happen from time to time (even for murder suspects).

Comment: @chirlu thank you! I thought that also Germany would hand over its citizen (without his/her agreement) to e.g. US for a crime committed over there, which does not have capital punishment included on the "menu". I wonder how we (I am a Finn) do. Putting aside my morale, I would still hesitate having a "serious party" in US and then escape to Finland, where a 1st time murderer de facto serves 6-8 years (1st time offender by default gets 50% off of the nominal 10-15 years life sentence (the "50% off" gets wiped off if you behave badly eg return late from your holidays)

Comment: To avoid confusion: When mentioning eg the "50% reduction" or "holidays" I sounded like I would be ridiculing the "sloppy" system. I have not enough knowledge to do that. But, what I know is that the, while there are people who repeatedly end up in prison, the approach where the prison tries to develop people who are in (schools etc.) and promote a soft landing once you are free, clearly also pays off, both for the society and for the offender-inmates.

Comment: @IllusiveBrian: not about Western countries (but the question is about Asian countries, so no reason to restrict), but gambling (except in a few casinos) and using drugs (weeds,...) is forbidden to Korean citizen, even abroad. People have been prosecuted before, for example a K-pop idol that put pictures of him gambling in a foreign country on SNS. The rationale is that Korean people "misbehaving" abroad brings shame to their country.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> why wouldn't they allow Hong Kong to punish the people who committed illegal acts in China to be tried in Hong Kong under Hong Kong's laws and sent to a Hong Kong prison?

The whole point of this is that all sorts of "political crimes" under Chinese law are legal in Hong Kong. If people were tried for these under HK law in HK they would be acquitted.